# AutoMapper - Creating map for an interface member

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have an interface

```
internal interface IAttributeModel
    {
        string Name { get; set; }

        int Id { get; set; }

        string AttType { get; set; }
    }
```

And a class implementing the interface

```
public class Currency:IAttributeModel
    {
        private string _type;

        public Currency()
        {
           _type = "Currency";
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        string IAttributeModel.AttType
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { _type = value; }
        }
    }
```

Above class has implemented one property explicitly.

And my entity does look like the following.

```
public class ProviderAttribute
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AttType { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have created a simple mapping

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entities.ProviderAttribute, Models.Currency>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Models.Currency, Entities.ProviderAttribute>();
```

Above mapping always setting overwriting Currency object's AttType property to null at the time of mapping. I this is probably happening because Currency is explicitly implementing IAttributeModel interface and my mapping is not able to find that.

How can I enforce my mapping to look into IAttributeModel interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the Currency object to the Interface type IAttributeModel:

```
Mapper.Map((IAttributeModel)currency, providerAttribute);
```

And you have to let AutoMapper know how to map the interface:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProviderAttribute, Currency>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Currency, ProviderAttribute>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ProviderAttribute, IAttributeModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<IAttributeModel, ProviderAttribute>();
```